# LVM misalignment: lvcreate causes alignment inconsistency

Tags: lvm, raid, disk

When creating a logical volume using the following commands the kernel log tells me there is some misalignment going on:

```
$ sudo vgcreate shinymarengo --dataalignment 1M /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
  Volume group "shinymarengo" successfully created

$ sudo lvcreate --type raid5 -L 4T --nosync --stripesize 1M -n shinymarengo_data shinymarengo
  WARNING: New raid5 won't be synchronised. Don't read what you didn't write!
  Logical volume "shinymarengo_data" created.
```

At first you'd think everything is fine, but when looking in `dmesg` there are some warnings:

```
[  +0.000052] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-3 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=512, start=0
[  +0.000010] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-5 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=0
[  +0.000010] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-3 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=512, start=0
[  +0.000008] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-5 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=0
[  +0.000290] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-3 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=512, start=0
[  +0.000009] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-5 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=0
[  +0.000008] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-3 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=512, start=0
[  +0.000008] device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device dm-5 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=0
```

And `lsblk` seems to tell the same story:

```
$ lsblk -t
NAME                                      ALIGNMENT  MIN-IO  OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED       RQ-SIZE   RA WSAME
sda                                               0    4096       0    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      58  128   32M
├─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data_rmeta_0          0    4096       0    4096     512    1                 128  128   32M
│ └─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data               -1 1048576 2097152    4096     512    1                 128 6144    0B
└─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data_rimage_0         0    4096       0    4096     512    1                 128  128   32M
  └─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data               -1 1048576 2097152    4096     512    1                 128 6144    0B
sdb                                               0    4096       0    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      58  128   32M
├─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data_rmeta_1        512    4096       0    4096     512    1                 128  128   32M
│ └─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data               -1 1048576 2097152    4096     512    1                 128 6144    0B
└─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data_rimage_1       512    4096       0    4096     512    1                 128  128   32M
  └─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data               -1 1048576 2097152    4096     512    1                 128 6144    0B
sdc                                               0    4096       0    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      58  128   32M
├─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data_rmeta_2          0    4096       0    4096     512    1                 128  128   32M
│ └─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data               -1 1048576 2097152    4096     512    1                 128 6144    0B
└─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data_rimage_2         0    4096       0    4096     512    1                 128  128   32M
  └─shinymarengo-shinymarengo_data               -1 1048576 2097152    4096     512    1                 128 6144    0B
```

Is there something I can do differently to get rid of the misalignment, or may this just be a bug?

Edit - platform details:

- Raspberry Pi 4B 2GB
- Raspbian Buster
- Linux 4.19.108
- LVM 2.03.02(2)

Comment: which distro, kernel, lvm versions?

Comment: @frostschutz I added them